# Ruby factory method to call private setter

Tags: ruby

I want to create a factory for a class, which will call a private setter. Is this possible?

Doing this:

```
class Foo
  def self.from_bar(bar)
    f = new bar.foo_id # bar has the id of the foo object I want to make
    f.bar = bar        # but I also wanna store the bar object in foo
    f
  end

  def initialize(id)
  end

  private
  attr_writer :bar

  # lazily load and memoize bar if needed and construction was not
  # made from factory method
  def bar
    @bar ||= ...
  end
end
```

results in a `NoMethodError: private method` error. I can `send` the method, but I'm looking for a non hacky way to do it.

EDIT: Changed attr_accessor to attr_writer and added memoized reader to reveal more of my intent here.

Comment: Here's a question, why do you want to set it from your factory method and then keep the setter private? Is the intention that the `bar` attribute is set, then both immutable an inaccessible? - If it shouldn't be changeable after initialising, why not pass it to the new method as a second argument?

Comment: Why not make `bar` a constructor argument, and have it passed in via the factory's `from_bar` method?

Comment: Yes, the intent is for it to be immutable after being set and totally inaccessible from outside of the object. The catch is that it's not necessary it'll be available during the object construction, it can be lazily pulled when needed by a private memoized reader (`@bar ||= ...`). So I'm only worried about the writer here actually. Adding a second parameter (maybe even nillable) to the constructor seems like a smell since it's not related at all to the normal initialization with a simple id and that will be even more pronounced with more such factories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible only with a hacky approach:

```
class Foo
  def self.from_bar(bar)
    new(bar.foo_id).tap { |f| f.send(:bar=, bar) }
    # or, better:
    new(bar.foo_id).tap { |f| f.instance_variable_set(:@bar, bar) }
  end

  private
  attr_accessor :bar
end
```

Honestly, making `attr_accessor` private makes a little sense, though.

Comment: How is intentionally breaking encapsulation "better"? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev in many different ways, the most important thing here would be: it’s about initialization of an instance variable and the latter variant is more explicit.

Comment: "making attr_accessor private makes a little sense" - depends. I frequently define private attr_readers, for example. It's all about public api. If a thing isn't public, it's a hint that you shouldn't normally use it (from outside).

Comment: Initialization of the instance variable is implementation detail of attr_accessor. The intended api is the setter. :shrug:

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the intended API cannot be private, otherwise, it’s not an API. I am not at all into this fashionable bullshit like 10 levels of abstractions and self-defending everything, protecting the code from myself.

Comment: wut? Interface is interface, private or public. If you define a setter, you might as well use it. Else you can define a reader only. Or not define anything at all. Encapsulation shouldn't be violated without serious need, and here I don't see it. (IMHO, naturally)

Comment: Thanks, I think the instance var setter is the approach I'll do for now and not do an accessor at all. I was only trying to do the accessor to allow the factory to set the var.

Comment: One could argue that calling a private setter is also a kind of encapsulation violation, but I see it as necessary evil, because of ruby's explicit receiver/private methods behaviour.

Comment: Also I might be talking out of my ass here, and I need to go lie down for a bit. :)

Comment: Both ways def *are* encapsulation breaking, I was just initially hoping the static factory method would be within the "encapsulation scope" of either private or protected but it seems there' no way around it.

Comment: @eirc: yeah, not in ruby. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

Ruby allows you to call private methods from anywhere using the `send` method.

Your factory would look something like this:

```
class FooFactory

  def FooFactory.build(bar)
    foo = Foo.new(generate_id)
    foo.send('bar=', bar)
    foo 
  end 

  private

  def generate_id
    rand(999999)
  end 

end
```

Then simply call:

```
FooFactory.build('bar')
```

Note, this is a standard pattern for factories, the send line would also work in your code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Having re-read the question, I believe this may be the answer.

- You don't need a private attr_accessor, you can just set an instance variable in the initialize method.
- It seems that storing the object is part of initialization, and shouldn't then be changeable.

I've come to the conclusion that a factory is not needed, and this can all be done in the initialize method.

```
class Foo

  def initialize(id, bar)
    @id = id
    @bar = bar
  end

end
```

Note: You could then make bar accessible with an attr_reader. Which will define `bar` but not `bar=`.

```
attr_reader :bar
```

Comment: My issue with this is that I want lots of those factories keeping the option to initialize the object from various facets. I don't really like leaking this to the constructor. The cleanest thing that would work with the constructor would be to give it an `id_or_bar` argument, do a case and proceed accordingly. Maybe that's the ruby way. What I really need is overloading the constructor and that's the way the stdlib does it IIRC.

Comment: @eric you could always make it an optional variable `def initialize(id, bar=nil)`. Then a condition to create a bar (if one's needed) when it's not provided. e.g. `@bar = bar || generate_bar`